# How do i define grpc async method in python which mypy would accept?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, grpc, mypy

I have a grpc service - using mypy-protobuf, the generated code looks as follows (names changed) :

```py
class MyServicer(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def Segment(
        self,
        request: my_pb2.MyRequest,
        context: grpc.ServicerContext,
    ) -> google.protobuf.empty_pb2.Empty:
```

Following the example from [grpc helloworld](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/async_greeter_server.py), i have written my code as follows :

```py
class MyServer(my_pb2_grpc.MyServicer):
    async def Segment(  # type: ignore
        self, request: my_pb2.MyRequest, context: grpc.aio.ServicerContext
    ) -> Empty:
        logging.info("Received request, sleeping for 4 seconds...")
        await asyncio.sleep(4)
        logging.info("Sleep completed, responding")
        return Empty()
```

If i remove the "# type: ignore", mypy complains "Return type "Coroutine[Any, Any, Empty]" of "Segment" incompatible with return type "Empty" in supertype "MyServicer". The application runs fine, but I would like to not have to ignore the typecheck. Is there a right way to do this?

Note: I found this tangentially related [issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5385#issuecomment-407281656) at mypy, which suggests that for protocols, the abstract methods *should not* be defined as async, but the implementation still can be.

Comment: `MyServicer` and `MyService` need to define `Segment` the same. They either both need to use `async def` or both need to use `def`.

Comment: Here's what you say: any `MyServicer` implementation should implement method `Segment` returning `Empty` instance. Then `MyServer` declares `Segment` as returning `Awaitable[Empty]` - and this is incompatible with parent class definition. If this is supposed to be async, declare it async in abstract parent. Otherwise there can be call like `segment = self.Segment()` in some parent method, that will result in a bug in child class (due to missing `await`).

Comment: @SUTerliakov - the question comes up for two reasons a) the base class definition is generated by mypy-protobuf, so manually editing it would mean manual editing whenever the generated code changes. Secondly, for protocols, mypy does accept "def xxx" in the base class, and "async def xxx" in the derived class, so perhaps this should work for grpc case also?